# Need help with a second-degree Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It says to let T<sub>2</sub>(x) be the second degree polynomial for the function
f(x) = 6 + xe<sup>4x</sup> where a=0. 
 
I need to find T<sub>2</sub>(1). 
I thought it was just a taylor expansion and look at the second term, which I got to be 1. But It's wrong. Am I messing up my definitions here? Thanks.

Comment: The second-degree polynomial includes the zero and one degree terms.

Comment: Do you know what a second degree polynomial is?

Comment: Make sure you are not confusing the second degree term of the Taylor polynomial with the second degree Taylor polynomial itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second degree Taylor Polynomial centered around $a=0$ would be:

$$T_2(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2$$
$$T_2(1) = f(0) + f'(0) + \frac{f''(0)}{2}$$